# Fast Way to reserve Ports in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sockets, port, udpclient

I have a need for my application to reserve certain port numbers. All I need to do is reserve them. I don't have to receive messages or anything. What is the fastest and easiest way to do this. I've tried the following:

```
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver1 = New UdpClient("localhost", 2020)
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver2 = New UdpClient("localhost", 2220)
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver3 = New UdpClient("localhost", 2021)
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver4 = New UdpClient("localhost", 2221)
```

But I think this reserves a random port to listen for messages coming from the port #'s I specified, because when I look at my ports I see that my application has reserved ports 4702 - 4705, when I wanted it to reserve the ports listed above.

I know that my application should not have to do this, but I don't work in fluffy coder candy land where everything is designed properly.

Thanks

Comment: `fluffy coder candy land` really?

Comment: Wrong flavor.  A client doesn't need a particular port.  A server (aka listener) does.  Having a server start listening "early" isn't meaningful.

Comment: I think that inheriting this application has permanently damaged my understanding of what a client and server are supposed to do. What we do is just have each side open hard coded ports and start sending and receiving data. Don't ask me why its that way though, I can only change 1 side of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was closer to my answer than I thought. The following works:

```
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver1 = New UdpClient(New Net.IPEndPoint(address, 2020))
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver2 = New UdpClient(New Net.IPEndPoint(address, 2220))
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver3 = New UdpClient(New Net.IPEndPoint(address, 2021))
ClientNetwork.hack_port_reserver4 = New UdpClient(New Net.IPEndPoint(address, 2221))
```